# Construct a DFA with reduced states equivalent to 10 + (0 + 11)0*1

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I have found this question in a book. I could convert it into its equivalent DFA. But the problem is with the "reduced state" part. I think the answer given in the book is wrong. What would be the DFA with its reduced states? I am giving the converting steps for reference:
[image]

The reduced DFA as given in the book: 
[image]

So, what should the DFA with reduced states look like?

Comment: The arrow from $q_1$ to $q_2$ should be labeled $1$, and there should be a self-loop at $q_2$ labeled $0$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you sir. Is there any short-cut way to get minimized DFA? Are q1 and q2 equal states in the DFA before the DFA with reduced states?

Comment: There are several algorithms for minimizing DFAs, which you can look up. I should note that your DFAs are "incomplete" (some states are missing outgoing edges), but this corresponds to throwing out at most one state of a "complete" DFA.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks again

Comment: I think we need another state to which the transition will occur if there is any input 0,1 after it reaches the accept state and the new state will self loop with input 0,1. In this way, we can ensure the string is not accepted if it does not end at the accept state.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hope this helps!  The answer in your picture is wrong because it has two transactions for symbol ' 1'. Which violates the property of DFA.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your book results, first of all they reduce to FA and then they convert to DFA, just like NDFA to DFA.
So that in the second picture actual result comes like this, but they forget to mention some input state in $q_f$ and $q_3$.